# Passing query parameters rest client

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a rest service that retrieves data from a database and returns it to the client. i want the client that is invoking the service to pass parameters to use them in sql query `select` and display the server output in console. this is what i've managed to do:

```
@GET
    @Path("Result")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getPerson(@QueryParam("nom") String nom, @QueryParam("prenom") String prenom) {
        ArrayList <Persons> persons= new ArrayList<Persons>();
        Persons person = new Persons();

        String query = "Select * from persons where nom=' " + nom + "' and prenom ='" + prenom + "'";
        System.out.println(query);
        bdcon = new BDConnexion();
        try {
            conn = BDConnexion.ConnecterBD();
            res = bdcon.getResultSet(query, conn);
            while (res.next()) {
                person.setNom(res.getString(1));
                person.setPrenom(res.getString(2));
                persons.add(person);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PersonService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        String json = new Gson().toJson(persons);
        return json;
    }
```

rest client:

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webresource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/PersonServ/rest/Persons/Result")
.queryParam("nom", nom)
.queryParam("prenom",prenom);
ClientResponse response = webresource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
 if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
               throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + response.getStatus());
            }
            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            System.out.println(output);
```

I'm not getting any errors but the client class is not displaying any results. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What does this `System.out.println(query);` prints?

Comment: it just prints the sql query i used it to check my sql syntax

Comment: I know that, I'm asking what it actually prints to see if there is something wrong on the query.

Comment: it does not print anything

Comment: There is your problem then. No query, no data, no return to the json.

Comment: Well, I find a little thing that may be causing your problem. You left an extra space on the query parameter: `nom=' " + nom + "'` when it should be `nom='" + nom + "'` Try that and let me know.

Comment: Another thing, you should initialize `Persons person = new Persons();` inside the while because java will use the reference for this object, therefore only the last result of your query will be added as all elements to the list.

Comment: sorry i didn't notice i actually had an error in my query i fixed it but still there is no result

Comment: Watch out for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: I moved Persons person = new Persons() inside while as you said but still nothing @JorgeCampos

Comment: Add inside your while: `System.out.println(res.getString(1));` and see what it prints. If it prints nothing it means either there are no results for the query you tried or there are still errors on your query. Note that this is the first step to solve the problem. The query isn't returning data, once this has been fixed we will see if there are any more problems.

Comment: @JorgeCampos You were right the error was in the query, i was passing a different type of parameter to the service i fixed it now everything is working fine Thanks.

Comment: That's great. Let compile everything as an answer.

Comment: I've added it as an answer. Please consider in accepting it if you like so. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments the actual problem is in the query. There are few things that should be fixed also.

**First:**

```
String query = "Select * from persons where nom=' " + nom + "' and prenom ='" + prenom + "'";
                                                 ^
                                                 |_ There is an extra space here. Take it out
```

But this is just to show you that you should be aware of the problems that comes with concatenating parameters in a query.

**Second:** Your code is prone to [SQLInjection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) as mentioned by @peeskillet in comments. In order to avoid that you should use Prepared Statements, something like this:

```
conn = BDConnexion.ConnecterBD();
String selectSQL = "select * from persons where nom=? and prenom=?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
preparedStatement.setString(1, nom);
preparedStatement.setString(2, prenom);
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL);
while (rs.next()) {
   ....
```

Don't forget to close the resources and the connection on the `finnaly` block of your `try`

**Third:** Initialize the `Persons person = new Persons();` inside the while loop. Java work with references so instantiating it outside of the loop you will result in a list filled with objects pointing to the same reference which will result in all objects on your list with the same values (last one of the loop).